# Automatically derive instances for sealed ADT's predictably

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless, scalacheck

Is it possible to automatically create instances for sealed ADT's?

I was able to create using [scalacheck-shapeless](https://github.com/alexarchambault/scalacheck-shapeless) library but it creates random instances for sum types. I would like to create each instance for sum type predictably.

For example:

```scala
sealed trait Base
case class BaseIntString(i: Int, s: String) extends Base
case class BaseDoubleBoolean(d: Double, b: Boolean) extends Base
```

**Question:** Program should automatically derive one instance for `BaseIntString` and one for `BaseDoubleBoolean` predictably.

Comment: Do you mean something like `Gen.oneOf[Base](BaseIntString(1, "a"), BaseDoubleBoolean(1.1, true))`?

Comment: I want to derive those automatically, I do not want to create them manually and select one of them.
My use case is not property based testing but I want to generate json for documentation purpose and store it in file for all the possible request and responses. 
So basically I want function which takes just base class and then generate one instance for each subclass predictably.

Comment: You would have to derive "default" arguments as well. Which would require you to define something like "default" String, Int, Double, etc. And then make it a typeclass and both use it for derivation as well as derive for new types. No library will do it for you out of the box.

Comment: Yes, I have `Arbitrary` instances available for every leaf type in scope, for example, `String`, `Int`, `Boolean`, `Person` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own gen derivation using shapeless, as described here:

- http://enear.github.io/2016/09/27/bits-of-shapeless-1/
- http://enear.github.io/2016/09/27/bits-of-shapeless-2/

Also, there's an example of deriving structural comparing typeclass instance using this guide:

https://github.com/ivan71kmayshan27/ShapelesDerivationExample

It probably looks like a thing you want, you might take derivation part and insert your own logic there.